# How about cleanup in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am newbie to Sqoop. I don't know I am asking the right question or not please correct if I am wrong.

When I do the import operation using sqoop to import the relational data into HDFS the output will be stored in HDFS. After completion of the process still the data present at HDFS side.

Here my question is, for every requirement by the user at the HDFS side, a file will create and it will be there permanently or it will be deleted after a while

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data will remain there unless you delete explicitly. You can write for cron jobs which will delete data at schedule intervals.